# Need help on user story with multiple condition

Tags: agile, user-story

I have the following user story:

- As a registered user i can request for a new license key

with the following condition

- When the user request a license key they required to enter some
  hardware id

Should i create another user story base on this condition? example

- As a registered user i can request a new license key only when
  hardware id is provided.

In a situation when i have multiple condition should i create many user story to fit in the condition?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It actually depends on the story size (i.e. its complexity). If the team feels that implementing/testing each condition is a fairly independent activity with its own complexity, then you can go for different stories.

However, in most cases, the conditions are trivial - and hence can be accommodated as different acceptance criteria on the same user story.

Answer (score 2):

Are there different ways of asking for requesting a license key? Can you deliver them individually whilst generating value for the customer?

If so, they are possibly multiple stories. If not, they are definitely not separate stories.

Stories need to be independent, negotiable, valuable, estimable, small and testable (INVEST). So make them as small and independent as possible, while keeping them valuable.

Answer (score 1):

Story:

```
As a [registered user],
I want to [request a new license key for my new hardware]
So that [I can use the product on my new hardware]
```

Test Scenario:

```
Given: a registered user and the new hardware information
When: a new license key is requested
Then: verify the user registration AND the hardware information AND issue the new key
```